# Why does this row don't wrap in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, row

What the problem is I have to render some texts which are in a row and also it should wrap when it doesn't have enough space but the row does not wrap.

I have used wrapping it `Expanded`, `Wrap`, and tried some stackoverflow answers but none of them work

Below is my code for it

```
Widget xyz(List _list) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 40, 10),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Title : ',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13),
          ),
          Wrap(children: [
            Row(children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    '${_list[i]}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                  ),
                ),
            ]),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          xyz([
            'Text1',
            'Text2',
            'Text3',
            'Text4',
            'Text5',
            'Text6',
            'Text7',
          ]),
          //other widgets
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the output I am getting

[image: Output]

I want the 'Text6' & 'Text7' `Text` widgets to go on the next line.

Comment: If you are seeing this, this is expected behavior: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54896

Comment: Hi, I don't think you understood my question though, probably the question was not clear. I have updated my question and mentioned what kind of output I want .

Comment: It's probably some incorrect usage of ParentDataWidget, give me a minute to test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working example:

The issues are incorrect Flexible (Expanded) placing, and your Wrap had a Row child instead of directly placed children.

```
Widget xyz(List _list) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 40, 10),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Title : ',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++)
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      '${_list[i]}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          xyz([
            'Text1',
            'Text2',
            'Text3',
            'Text4',
            'Text5',
            'Text6',
            'Text7',
          ]),
          //other widgets
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This sure is working but still why does having a `Row` widget makes up such a problem?

Comment: Wrap calculates it's children size and puts them where space is available. If Row is a child of a Wrap, wrap only sees the Row's size, so instead of 7 children of 100 width, which it can split in "rows", it only sees a single child of 700 width, which it can't split.

Comment: Thanks, understood my mistake

Comment: Glad to know I could help